Who wrote the book of Job?
Since there is no direct attribution made in the book, the basis for some of the hypotheses for authorship seems to be mosty derived from certain features of the book's content. The style of writing, the use of Aramaisms, the context of the characters, etc. are all used to base educated assumptions on and suggest that the author had to live during a certain time, have a certain nationality, etc. The suggested candidate for authorship sounds very foreign to the book although attempts are made to harmonise him very well.
My question is that although this approach would be the normal way of trying to solve this 'unknown', should we still consider it a sound practice since the book is largely poetry?

Hi Mintaka, good question! I've removed the third paragraph as you were beginning to Answer it yourself. I think you could improve this further by simplifying it. If you have an Answer you would like to contribute, it's perfectly okay to write it as an Answer to your own question.

Oh dear, my apologies. Still learning. I thought answers required a lot more than I had there, and, to be honest, I did not consider it an answer. I meant to clean up the question not too long after posting it but got busy. Will do so a bit later.

No worries! A full answer should probably have a little more in the way of references or explaining your reasoning - but it's a decent start! But yeah, best practice is to just focus on the Question itself, and avoid trying to lead people to give a particular answer.

I was not seeking to lead people to give a particular answer, simply wanted to show that the rationale followed by accademics who side against Moses as author could be applied to prove his authorship, hence my question. But I will sit down and clean it all up still. Thanks

From internal evidence within the book, Job, himself, would have been contemporary with Abraham's grandfather. The rudimentary wording and concepts point to an original language more basic than Hebrew. It is possible that Moses translated it from something like Cuneiform into Hebrew and that he obtained the original (or copied it) from Jethro, the priest, in Midian. It is probably the oldest known complete book, dating, possibly, to about 2,500 B.C. Of course, everything is disputed in academia and one will find multiple theories abounding. Elihu is most probably the author.

Thanks Nigel, do you perhaps have resources to consult for Elihu's authorship? Would like to see the rationale behind it.

@Mintaka Yes, if you download the PDF of my book 'The Patience of Job'  (all the discourses of Job versed into accurate common metre) the appendix has historic information. Elihu's presence (not speaking at the first) was probably to act as a scribe, initially, but he was moved to make his own contribution, after which the Lord spoke.

Thanks I will do so!

This resource might be helpful:
BIBLICA ET ORIENTALIA—N. 22
ANTON C. M. BLOMMERDE
Northwest Semitic Grammar and Job
ROME
PONTIFICAL BIBLICAL INSTITUTE
1969
© Iura editionis et versionis reservantur
Blommerde, A. C. M. (1969). Northwest Semitic Grammar and Job (pp. iii – iv). Pontifical Biblical Institute.

@Nigel Thanks for the link to your book. (1) Am I correct in assuming that it may be freely distributed? (2) I see that you have used non-standard verse boundaries. This may be to suit your versification, but somewhat scrambles the ability to locate familiar passages. Might it be possible to somehow accommodate annotations for both new and traditional versifications? (Maybe smaller point subscript verse numbers for traditional. || My ME Electrical thesis cited Job 38:2 at the front :-) . | Job 38:12-13 is sometimes used as a quote. ... .

@RussellMcMahon 1. Yes, it may be freely distributed. 2. It took many months to perform the mental gymnastics necessary to accurately convey the text in both the rythym and the rhyme necessary for metric expression. This is the first time it has been so presented in the English language. I leave it to the reader to compare it to other numerations. (The original Hebrew text is not numerated at all.)

@NigelJ  Many thanks. I'll pass the link on. || I'm aware that our verse divisions are 'modern stuff. As are vowels, & sentence divisions and punctuation in Greek. I'm not at all complaining about your divisions, but suggesting that some almost unnoticeable indicators of traditional versification could be useful. || I've recently been browsing through Moffat's translation - he rearranges verse order and moves chunks of text around to their "original" positions and may remove or marginal notes later "glosses".  || I greatly appreciate JB Phillips but wish he'd added unobtrusive verse markers.

Job Introduction (ESV Study Bible 20220328)
Author
While Job is one of the most profound books of the Bible, its anonymous author can be known only through reading between its lines. Certainly he can be numbered among “the wise” (cf. Prov. 24:23), given his fondness for proverbs, which he quotes to develop a point: “those who plow iniquity and sow trouble reap the same” (Job 4:8); “man is born to trouble as the sparks fly upward” (5:7); “a stupid man will get understanding when a wild donkey’s colt is born a man!” (11:12).
Though the story of Job has its setting outside Israel to the east and south (Uz is related to Edom, which may be the setting of the book, cf. 2:11; 6:19; Lam. 4:21), the author of Job is a Hebrew, thoroughly immersed in the Hebrew Scriptures.
The author of Job was a well-traveled individual who could draw on a wealth of knowledge and experience. He knew the constellations (Job 9:9; 38:31), could discuss meteorology (38:22–38) or describe a sophisticated mining operation (28:1–11). He could refer to skiffs of papyrus reed plying the waters (9:26), or the plants that grew in the marshes (8:11–19). He had observed ostriches, eagles, mountain goats, hippopotamuses, crocodiles, and war horses (chs. 39–41). As was true of all the wise, he made extensive use of nature analogies to explain and defend moral truths.
Etymologically the name Job could be related to the Hebrew word for “enemy,” with reference to either Job’s attitude to God or his response to suffering. The name might also be a contracted form of “Where is my father?” But it is difficult to know, because its actual meaning was already lost to the earliest rabbinic commentators. However, the name is known outside the Bible. It is the name of the prince of Ashtaroth in Bashan in the Amarna tablets (c. 1350 b.c.), and the name of a Palestinian chief in an Egyptian text (c. 2000 b.c.). At Ugarit a version of the name appears in a list of palace personnel.

Any internal clues about when the book was written will also narrow the field.

This is a matter of opinion. Here are several theories:
Job himself.  'Advocates of this viewpoint emphasize the intimate portrayal of his trials and tribulations, arguing that such depth of emotion could only emanate from firsthand experience.' 1
Moses or Solomon
'Considering the ancient context and themes of perseverance and faith evident in the Book of Job, some scholars have proposed Moses as its author.'.. Similarly, Solomon is famed for his wisdom writings, so he too as a possible author suggested by traditionalists. 2
Unknown of Great Antiquity. Other scholars suggest that the basic story is great antiquity but the author cannot be known. It may be based on an old folk tale, which later authors embellished by creating the dialog which comprises the bulk of the text as we now have it.
Unknown post-Exilic. Many critical scholars see evidence of Babylonian influence, leading to the idea that it was written during the Babylonian Exile and probably edited later, when the  prologue and epilogues were added, as well as possibly the speech of Elihu, which does not fit neatly into the dialog and was probably not part of the original. 3

Thanks for your answer. Appreciate your honesty.

I have seen that the possibility of Mosaic authorship is always presented as hanging from the tether of a rabinic tradition or something, but, a faithful consideration of who Moses would have been based on his unusual educational background as next in line of a world empire, it seems obvious to me that he is the only Hebrew (who lived that long ago) capable of rendering such a literary masterpiece. Compared to the other five books it seems like both Job and Genesis were the products of his time tending Jethro's sheep.
